# Doesn't work example with Keras framework

Tags: python, pandas, theano, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to study `Keras` library and created follow script as example:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import np_utils

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import memory_profiler as mprof


def write_preds(preds, fname):
    pd.DataFrame({"ImageId": list(range(1,len(preds)+1)), "Label": preds}).to_csv(fname, index=False, header=True)


start = time.time()
# read data
train = pd.read_csv("..\\data\\train_small.csv")
labels = train.ix[:,0].values.astype('int32')
X_train = (train.ix[:,1:].values).astype('float32')
print 'Loaded train', time.time() - start, mprof.memory_usage()

test = pd.read_csv("..\\data\\test_small.csv")
X_test = (test.values).astype('float32')
# convert list of labels to binary class matrix
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(labels)
print 'Loaded test', time.time() - start, mprof.memory_usage()

# pre-processing: divide by max and substract mean
scale = np.max(X_train)
X_train /= scale
X_test /= scale

mean = np.std(X_train)
X_train -= mean
X_test -= mean

input_dim = X_train.shape[1]
nb_classes = y_train.shape[1]
print 'Prepare data', time.time() - start, mprof.memory_usage()
# Here's a Deep Dumb MLP (DDMLP)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=20, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2, init='uniform'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
print 'Created model', time.time() - start, mprof.memory_usage()
# we'll use MSE (mean squared error) for the loss, and RMSprop as the optimizer
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
print 'Training ...', time.time() - start, mprof.memory_usage()
model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=16, show_accuracy=True, verbose=1)
print 'Generating ...', time.time() - start, mprof.memory_usage()
preds = model.predict_classes(X_test, verbose=0)
print 'Predicted', time.time() - start, mprof.memory_usage()

write_preds(preds, "..\\data\\keras-mlp.csv")
print 'Finished experiment', time.time() - start, mprof.memory_usage()
```

In my opinion, this script should work :), however I got next error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:/new_test.py", line 58, in <module>
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=16, show_accuracy=True, verbose=1)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 507, in fit
    shuffle=shuffle, metrics=metrics)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 226, in _fit
    outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line 357, in __call__
    return self.function(*inputs)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 606, in __call__
    storage_map=self.fn.storage_map)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 595, in __call__
    outputs = self.fn()
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\op.py", line 768, in rval
    r = p(n, [x[0] for x in i], o)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\blas.py", line 1612, in perform
    z[0] = numpy.asarray(numpy.dot(x, y))
```

> ```
> ValueError: ('shapes (9,784) and (20,64) not aligned: 784 (dim 1) != 20 (dim 0)', (9L, 784L), (20L, 64L))
> Apply node that caused the error: Dot22(<TensorType(float32, matrix)>, <TensorType(float32, matrix)>)
> Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, matrix)]
> Inputs shapes: [(9L, 784L), (20L, 64L)]
> Inputs strides: [(3136L, 4L), (256L, 4L)]
> Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
>
> HINT: Re-running with most Theano optimization disabled could give you a back-trace of when this node was created. This can be done with
> ```
>
> by setting the Theano flag 'optimizer=fast_compile'. If that does not
>   work, Theano optimizations can be disabled with 'optimizer=None'.
>       HINT: Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.

PS. Shapes data:

- Size of X_train (9L, 784L)
- Size of X_test (9L, 784L)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this line in your code

```
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=20, init='uniform'))
```

Why 20 input dimensions? MNIST has 28X28 images, i.e. an input dimension of `784`. The error message confirms that as well:

```
ValueError: ('shapes (9,784) and (20,64) not aligned: 784 (dim 1) != 20 (dim 0)', (9L, 784L), (20L, 64L))
```

You can further verify the size of your input

```
print "Size of X_train", x_train.shape
print "Size of X_test", x_test.shape
```

And accordingly change the line above to:

```
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=784, init='uniform'))
```

Comment: Yes, it helps. Now I got another `error` -> *ValueError: Input dimension mis-match. (input[0].shape[1] = 2, input[1].shape[1] = 8)*